# Prevent negative value after jquery calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, date-arithmetic

when I calculate the difference between the start date and end date - it is possible for the end date to be entered as being "before" the start date - therefore allowing a negative calculation value in "totaldays".   )I have used the "min" to ensure that the start date cannot be "before today".   )

also, is it possible for "total_days" result (result of calculation) to be hidden until the calculation is complete - ie so that you do not see the long decimal value: such as -15489.916666666666

I have tried to complete this on my own, but have very very limited javascript / jquery knowledge. I would value any response. :-)  Thank you

```
<title>Conference Form</title>



<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqueryui.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>

<table width="705" border="1" align="left" cellpadding="1">
  <form action="" method="get" name="myform">

  <tr>
    <td width="151"><label>Company Name</label></td>
    <td width="158"><input type="text" name="companyname" id="companyname" /></td>
    <td width="155">Enquiry Date</td>
    <td width="213"><input type="text" name="enquiry_date" id="enquiry_date" class="datepicker" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Conference Date In</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="conference_date_in" id="conference_date_in" class="datepicker" /></td>
    <td>Conference Date Out</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="conference_date_out" id="conference_date_out" class="datepicker" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Number of Delegates</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="no_of_delegates" id="no_of_delegates" /></td>
    <td>Total Days</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="total_days" id="total_days" /></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+100M +10D",dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'})
    ({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
        });


var enquiry_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date());
document.getElementById('enquiry_date').value = enquiry_date;

var calcDate = function() {
    var start = $('#conference_date_in').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#conference_date_out').datepicker('getDate');
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

    document.getElementById('total_days').value = days;
}


$('#conference_date_out').change(calcDate);
$('#conference_date_in').change(calcDate);
</script>
```

Comment: what exactly is the question here?  be specific about what you need help with... "please do it for me" questions don't get much traction around here

Comment: @ThinkingSites:  Do I multiply the "total_days" by 1?

Comment: @RobertLevy:  My apologies for not being specific enough-My question is: What route would I go about preventing a negative value from appearing in the "total_days" result? ie, if the end date is before the start date, then the result displays as negative...  how would I go about preventing that?  I hope that is more specific, my apologies again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap your UI update in an if statement

```
if( days >= 0 ) {
    document.getElementById('total_days').value = days;
} else {
    alert( "Nice try, but you can't go backwards in time" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're searching for the absolute value of a number (the value without a sign), use `Math.abs`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+100M +10D",dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });        

var enquiry_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', new Date());
$('#enquiry_date').val(enquiry_date);

var calcDate = function() {
    var start = $('#conference_date_in').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#conference_date_out').datepicker('getDate');
    if (start << end) {
        var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        $('total_days').val(days);
    } else {
        alert('Day Out must be after the Day In. Try again.');
    }
}


$('#conference_date_out').change(calcDate);
$('#conference_date_in').change(calcDate);

});
```